# I'm using jwt(expiresIn 24h) for sending reset password link to the user. Is there any way to invalidate token once it is used?

Tags: node.js

I want to invalidate a jwt once it is used without storing token into db. Is there any way to achieve it? Although I have gone through several medium and StackOverflow posts but did not get a proper answer.

Much much appreciated for the help.